# Why won't Scilab open an image file?

Tags: image, libraries, scilab, image-formats

I am trying to work with image files under Scilab, and I get stuck at the very beginning, unable to load an image file.

I have searched the help system as well as the Web, tried two versions of Scilab (because some of the answers I found say that 6.0 is incompatible with some image functions) and still drew a blank. Whatever I try, the imread function is simply not there.

Here is what I get:

Under Scilab 6.0.2:

```
--> clear

--> atomsSystemUpdate()
Scanning repository http://atoms.scilab.org/6.0 ... Done


--> atomsInstall("SIVP")
atomsInstallList: The package "SIVP" is not registered.
Please check on the ATOMS repository that it is available for Scilab 6.0 on Windows.
If it is, run atomsSystemUpdate() before trying atomsInstall(..) again.

at line    52 of function atomsError       ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.2\modules\atoms\macros\atoms_internals\atomsError.sci line 66 )
at line    78 of function atomsInstallList ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.2\modules\atoms\macros\atoms_internals\atomsInstallList.sci line 117 )
at line   233 of function atomsInstall     ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.2\modules\atoms\macros\atomsInstall.sci line 249 )


--> atomsInstall("IPCV")
 ans  =

    []


--> disp( atomsGetInstalled() );

!IPCV  4.1.2  user  SCIHOME\atoms\x64\IPCV\4.1.2  I  !


--> im=imread("Kratka220.tif")

Undefined variable: imread
```

Under Scilab 5.5.2:

```
-->clear
 
-->atomsSystemUpdate()
Scanning repository http://atoms.scilab.org/5.5 ... Done

 
-->atomsInstall("SIVP")
 ans  =
 
     []
 
-->atomsInstall("IPCV")
atomsInstallList: Pakiet IPCV nie jest dostępny.
<this is Polish for "Package IPCV is not available"; I installed 5.5.2 in Polish>
 !--error 10000 

at line      51 of function atomsError called by :  
at line      76 of function atomsInstallList called by :  
at line     233 of function atomsInstall called by :  
atomsInstall("IPCV")
 
 
-->disp( atomsGetInstalled() );
 
 
         column 1 to 4
 
!SIVP  0.5.3.2  user  SCIHOME\atoms\x64\SIVP\0.5.3.2  !
 
         column 5
 
!I  !
 
-->im=imread("Kratka220.tif")
                           !--error 4 
Niezdefiniowana zmienna: imread
  <this is Polish for "undefined variable">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After atomsInstall you have to restart Scilab to load the toolbox.

Comment: Worked like a charm, merci Stéphane!

Comment: Great. Can you validate the answer ?

Comment: I upvoted it, but I don't have enough reputation for my vote to show. And if there is another button for validation (different from upvoting), I cannot see it.